# T-SQL passing a table name dynamically inside WITH statement

Tags: t-sql, cursor, with-statement

I have the following code in T-SQL that reads table names from a cursor.

But I have problem with the scoping table name variable inside the `WITH` statement.

I can run this code when I explicitly set `dbo.@sys_name` to a synonym name like `dbo.mysysnonym` but when I put it as variable name like `dbo.@syn_name` it does not work.

```
 -- drop duplicates records from synonyms
 DECLARE @syn_name varchar(50)

 DECLARE s_cursor CURSOR FOR  
     SELECT name 
     FROM sys.synonyms  
     WHERE  base_object_name LIKE 'xyz%'

 OPEN s_cursor;

 FETCH NEXT FROM s_cursor INTO @syn_name;

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN

     FETCH NEXT FROM s_cursor INTO @syn_name;

     WITH  dedupTable AS 
     (
         SELECT 
             sys_id, 
             row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY sys_id ORDER BY sys_id) AS nr
         FROM 
             dbo.@syn_name
     )
     DELETE  FROM dedupTable
     WHERE nr > 1
END;

CLOSE s_cursor
DEALLOCATE s_cursor
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you cannot use variables as table names, so `dbo.@syn_name` will not work in a `FROM` clause.  Instead, you will have to use [Dynamic SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

Something like:

```
...
FETCH NEXT FROM s_cursor INTO @syn_name;
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)

SET @sql = N'
    WITH  dedupTable
    AS ( 
       SELECT sys_id, row_number() 
       OVER ( PARTITION BY sys_id ORDER BY sys_id  ) AS nr
       FROM dbo.' + @syn_name + '
    )
    DELETE  FROM dedupTable
    WHERE   nr > 1'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```